for loop with two counters in Delphi
I'm new to Delphi so I apologize for the banality of my question.
How can I write in Delphi a for loop with two counters like this in C++:
int i, j;
for (i=0, j=0; j<100; i++, j++) {
//do something
}

Thanks

You have to "unroll" the loop like this:
VAR I := 0;
FOR VAR J:=0 TO 99 DO BEGIN
  // Do Something
  INC(I)
END;


OK, it's clear. Thanks

In Delphi, a for loop can have only exactly one counter, and it can only step by 1. (It can, however, step either upwards, using to, or downwards, using downto.)
The other two loop constructs in the Delphi language are repeat and while.
With repeat, your example could be written like this:
i := 0;
j := 0;
repeat
  // Do something
  Inc(i);
  Inc(j);
until j = 100;

With while, it could look like this:
i := 0;
j := 0;
while j < 100 do
begin
  // Do something
  Inc(i);
  Inc(j);
end;


The correct way to "translate" a C(++) FOR loop into a repeating loop in Delphi is the WHILE loop, as that is, internally, what the FOR loop in C is compiled as (since it allows for no iterations to be performed, which a REPEAT loop doesn't).

@HeartWare as that is, internally, what the FOR loop in C is compiled as
Any notion of higher level control flow structures goes out the window when the code compiles. What you're left with are unconditional jumps (JMP) (which are essentially gotos) and conditional jumps (collectively referred to as Jxx). The latter perform the jump based on conditional bits maintained in the FLAGS register. For example, JNZ will jump if ZF (Zero Flag) is not set and JC will jump if CF (Carry Flag) is set.

@HeartWare I didn't want to go on and on on a whole tangent, but these details are rather crucial to understand what becomes of higher level control flow structures when you compile your code. My point here is that the exact arrangement and layout of the emitted machine code is wholly at the discretion of the compiler (up until the optimizer comes and spaghettifies the logic further).
From the point of view of the machine code/assembly, there's no discernible difference between a repeat-, a while-, a for- or an if-statement. Ofc, it's possible to look around for counters and checks.
